# Как вывести массив состоящий из кнопок?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как вывести массив состоящий из `button` в окне WPF?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться передавать между процедурами массив кнопок. Расскажите лучше свою _настоящую_ задачу.

Comment: Чтобы генерировать список кнопок, нужно создать <ItemsСontrol>, переопределить его <ItemTemplate> в виде кнопок. И байндинг должен быть на коллекцию ViewModel. Список из "Button" это извращение.

Answer (score 5):

Для генерации повторяющихся элементов управления в WPF принято не создавать элементы управления вручную, а полагаться на шаблоны. Например, можно создать модель со списком надписей на кнопках:

```
public class MainModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Buttons { get; private set; }

    public MainModel ()
    {
        Buttons = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
}
```

Задать надписи можно хотя бы в конструкторе:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        DataContext = new MainModel {
            Buttons = {
                "OK",
                "Cancel",
                "Apply",
            }
        };
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Тогда в XAML останется только вывести этот список в виде кнопок:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfButtonList.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вкладываете его в какой-нибудь ItemsControl. Например, ListBox:

```
<ListBox Items="{Binding ArrayOfButtons}"/>
```

Comment: _Спасибо за оперативный ответ. _

Comment: `ItemsControl` хватит...